# How to end outgoing call automatically in android java?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, phone-number, outgoing-call

I have an edit text where I input user's phone number and make a call and once the phone rings I want to end the call automatically rather than the user cutting up the call. How can I achieve this programatically ? 
Here is my MainActivityCode:

```
    phnum = edNumber.getText().toString();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    startActivity(callIntent);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To end a call, follow these steps:

1. Call the  [setDisconnected(DisconnectCause)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection.html#setDisconnected(android.telecom.DisconnectCause)) sending LOCAL as the parameter if the user terminated the call, or send REMOTE as the parameter if the other party terminated the call.
2. Call the destroy() method. 
   Know more pls [click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged)